# npm and yarn installation error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, yarnpkg

I've been trying to run a server development in Visual Studio Code for this but I keep getting an error

https://github.com/cobiwave/gatsby-simplefolio#readme

I already have all the Prerequisites but I am stuck at

> Then you can install the dependencies either using NPM or Yarn:

When I try `npm install` I keep getting an error that starts with this

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\gatsby-simplefolio\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
```

I also did the `npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root` and same thing happened

When I try `yarn` I keep getting this error

```
yarn : File D:\nodejs\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file D:\nodejs\yarn.ps1 is not digitally signed. You  
cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting       
execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for answering. I already solved it. Turns out the project is outdated. I checked out the owner and found this updated version and used it.

https://github.com/cobiwave/simplefolio

`npm start` worked for me. `yarn` still doesn't work but that's another problem for another day

Answer (score -1):

Try using node 13.14.0. I also ran got a node-sass related error when I tried to do `npm install` with this repo and I found [this issue](https://github.com/cobiwave/gatsby-simplefolio/issues/79). Once I downgraded to that lower version I was able to install.